# Cannot access to the file. No permission. Although [-rw-rw-rw]

Tags: php, linux, permissions

I'm using CentOS 6.5

User : Erik

I cannot access to the specific file although permission is `[-rw-rw-rw]`.
Why this happening.

**State:**

> --- Parent Directory ---
>   Dir Name : Source
>   Permission : [dr-r-x-r--] Owner : Erik
>
> --- Source File List ---
>   header.php    Erik [-rw-rw-rw-] : **Can read but cannot edit file.**
>   footer.php    Erik [-rw-rw-rw-] : **Can read but cannot edit file.**
>   banner.php    Erik [-rw-rw-rw-] : Can read and edit.
>   customer.php  Erik [-rw-rw-rw-] : Can read and edit.
>   list.php      Erik [-rw-rw-rw-] : Can read and edit.
>
> --- Result of `ls -alp`
>   drwxr-xr-x.  2 Erik Erik 4096 2017-03-15 11:33 ./
>   drwxr-xr-x. 14 Erik Erik 4096 2017-03-15 11:30 ../
>   -rw-rw-rw-.  1 Erik Erik 1102 2017-10-24 23:07 header.php
>   -rw-rw-rw-.  1 Erik Erik 680 2015-01-19 13:01 footer.php
>   -rw-rw-rw-.  1 Erik Erik 1449 2015-01-23 09:42 banner.php
>   -rw-rw-rw-.  1 Erik Erik 953 2014-12-03 09:31 customer.php
>   -rw-rw-rw-.  1 Erik Erik 810 2014-12-03 09:31 list.php

I can't understand why I can't edit the `header.php` and `footer.php` althogh I'm Erik with permission `-rw-rw-rw`.

Is there any way to edit `header.php` & `footer.php` file avoid to change permission of **Parent Directory**.
Someone please help me. This is very important to me.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Directory permissions are important too.

Comment: also group permissions too ... chown

Comment: check extended attributes: `getfacl *`, and go to serverfault.com

Comment: But I can edit `banner.php`. Only I cannot edit `header.php` & `footer.php`. It has same permission I think.

Comment: Post the result of this in your question:  cd Source; ls -alp

Comment: same permission and group is the same try a `ls -la` to this directory to see witch group used ...

Comment: Stack Overflow is a site for programming and development questions. This question appears to be off-topic because it is not about programming or development. See [What topics can I ask about here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) in the Help Center. Perhaps [Super User](http://superuser.com/) or [Unix & Linux Stack Exchange](http://unix.stackexchange.com/) would be a better place to ask.

Comment: Dude, you changed the question on us, making my answer downvoted.  Post ls -la or your files please.

Comment: @Nic Thank you. Result of `ls -alp` : `-rw-rw-rw- 1 Erik Erik [Size] [Date] [Filename]` all of the files have same property.

Comment: Post the real ls -alp in the question, we need to see the . and .. values as well.

Comment: I can't understand why someone down voted my question. Can he solve this problem? Does he think the mind of posting man?

Comment: @Nic, I posted the result of `ls -alp`.

Comment: Downvote: wrong site (other Stack sites deal with unix questions), incomplete question (missing details), question edits, contradiction between permissions on the directory and what was just posted, ...  :-)  SO users are very critical of questions, take it as a learning experience.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/157392/discussion-between-a-godnov-and-nic).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Cause of `SELinuX`. You can't edit file although you permission is `[-rw-rw-rw-]`.

The result of `ls -alp` shows that `SELinuX` is protecting your specific files.

The end of permission part, dot(.) means that file is protected by `SELinuX`.

If you want to edit file in owner permission, you have to change `SELinuX` property via `root`.

Comment: Thank you. I guessed it caused by `SELINUX`. Thank you.

Comment: I can edit file just now avoid to change permission of parent dir.